# Problem using ArcGIS API for Silverlight

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, visual-studio

I've install Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Microsoft Expression Blend 4, and ArcGIS API 3.0 for Silverlight. When I create a new project using a standard map application in Visual Studio, I see the error in design tab. When I create a project in Microsoft blend 4, I don't see any template and the appliction shows an error. How can I fix the problem?[image: visual studio error]

[image: microsoft expression blend error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the right configuration. Maybe you (or your partner) is on a 64 bit system, but you are trying to run it on a x86 system. Then, the metadata can't be loaded. Try to select the right configuration type, then clean the solution and finally rebuild the solution.